# displaying database field read as a link

Tags: c#, sql

i am reding data from database in a bulleted list as follow

```
<asp:BulletedList ID="BulletedList1" runat="server" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="description" 
            DataValueField="id">
        </asp:BulletedList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:chaaapaConnectionString4 %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [quiz]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

i want this to appear as a link. how can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try with DisplayMode="HyperLink"

```
<asp:BulletedList 
ID="BulletedList1" 
runat="server"  
DisplayMode="HyperLink"
DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
DataTextField="description" 
DataValueField="id">
</asp:BulletedList>
```